# Better to query once, then organize objects based on returned column value, or query twice with different conditions?

Tags: java, sql, database

I have a table which I need to query, then organize the returned objects into two different lists based on a column value. I can either query the table once, retrieving the column by which I would differentiate the objects and arrange them by looping through the result set, or I can query twice with two different conditions and avoid the sorting process. Which method is generally better practice?

```
MY_TABLE

NAME    AGE    TYPE
John    25     A
Sarah   30     B
Rick    22     A
Susan   43     B
```

Either `SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE`, then sort in code based on returned types, or

`SELECT NAME, AGE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE TYPE = 'A'` followed by

`SELECT NAME, AGE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE TYPE = 'B'`

Comment: Since the looping is within the code its better to follow that approach rather then firing two queries on the DB. Post an example to make your question clearer.

Comment: In general processing query results in your code is always faster.
Said that, you can order your rows by that column, so you only will have to find which index is the last one of the first group and split the list there.

Comment: It also depends on your dataset volume, for instance if you have a large data set, doing a select * without any condition might take some time, but if you have an index on your 'TYPE' column, then adding a where clause will reduce the time taken to execute the query. If you are dealing with a small data set, then doing a select * followed with your logic in the java code is a better approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logically, a DB query from a Java code will be more expensive than a loop within the code because querying the DB involves several steps such as connecting to DB, creating the SQL query, firing the query and getting the results back.

Besides, something can go wrong between firing the first and second query.

With an optimized single query and looping with the code, you can save a lot of time than firing two queries.

In your case, you can sort in the query itself if it helps:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY TYPE
```

In future if there are more types added to your table, you need not fire an additional query to retrieve it.

Answer (score 2):

It is heavily dependant on the context. If each list is really huge, I would let the database to the hard part of the job with 2 queries. At the opposite, in a web application using a farm of application servers and a central database I would use one single query.

For the general use case, IMHO, I will save database resource because it is a current point of congestion and use only only query.

The only objective argument I can find is that the splitting of the list occurs in memory with a hyper simple algorithm and in a single JVM, where each query requires a bit of initialization and may involve disk access or loading of index pages.

Answer (score 2):

In general, one query performs better.

Also, with issuing two queries you can potentially get inconsistent results (which may be fixed with higher transaction isolation level though ).

In any case I believe you still need to iterate through resultset (either directly or by using framework's  methods that return collections).

Answer (score 2):

From the database point of view, you optimally have exactly one statement that fetches exactly everything you need and nothing else. Therefore, your first option is better. But don't generalize that answer in way that makes you query more data than needed. It's a common mistake for beginners to select all rows from a table (no where clause) and do the filtering in code instead of letting the database do its job.

Answer (score 1):

You can query by two conditions:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE TYPE = 'A' OR TYPE = 'B'
```

This will do both for you at once, and if you want them sorted, you could do the same, but just add an order by keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE TYPE = 'A' OR TYPE = 'B' ORDER BY TYPE ASC
```

This will sort the results by type, in ascending order.

EDIT:
I didn't notice that originally you wanted two different lists. In that case, you could just do this query, and then find the index where the type changes from 'A' to 'B' and copy the data into two arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on your dataset volume, for instance if you have a large data set, doing a select * without any condition might take some time, but if you have an index on your 'TYPE' column, then adding a where clause will reduce the time taken to execute the query. If you are dealing with a small data set, then doing a select * followed with your logic in the java code is a better approach

Answer (score 1):

There are four main bottlenecks involved in querying a database.

1. The query itself - how long the query takes to execute on the server depends on indexes, table sizes etc.
2. The data volume of the results - there could be hundreds of columns or huge fields and all this data must be serialised and transported across the network to your client.
3. The processing of the data - java must walk the query results gathering the data it wants.
4. Maintaining the query - it takes manpower to maintain queries, simple ones cost little but complex ones can be a nightmare.

By careful consideration it should be possible to work out a balance between all four of these factors - it is unlikely that you will get the right answer without doing so.